# formdata is empty when its reach backend (Node js)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

- I'm trying to build an e-commerce application using React and Node.js. The problem I encountered is that when I try to add a new product, the details are not reaching the backend. I used FormData to append all the details, including images, to send to the backend. It correctly gives every value from the frontend, but when it reaches the backend controller, it's empty. I logged it using console.log(req.body), and it shows an empty object.

this one is the component where i add the product

```
`import React, { useState } from 'react'; import { addProduct } from '../../services/userApi';

`const Modal = ({ isOpen, onClose, title }) => { 

const [titles, setTitle] = useState(''); 
const [ram, setRam] = useState(''); 
const [price, setPrice] = useState(''); 
const [totalProducts, setTotalProducts] = useState(''); 
const [description, setDescription] = useState(''); 
const [images, setImages] = useState([]); 
const [previewImages, setPreviewImages] = useState([]);

const handleImageChange = (e) => { const files = Array.from(e.target.files); setImages([...images, ...files]);

// Update the state with preview images
const previews = files.map((file) => URL.createObjectURL(file));
setPreviewImages([...previewImages, ...previews]);};

const removeImage = (index) => { // Remove the selected image and its preview const updatedImages = [...images]; updatedImages.splice(index, 1); setImages(updatedImages);
const updatedPreviews = [...previewImages];
updatedPreviews.splice(index, 1);
setPreviewImages(updatedPreviews);};

const handleSubmit = async (e) => { e.preventDefault() try { console.log(titles,ram,price,totalProducts,description,images); // Create a FormData object to handle file uploads const formData = new FormData();

 // Append non-file fields
  formData.append('title', titles);
  formData.append('ram', ram);
  formData.append('price', price);
  formData.append('totalProducts', totalProducts);
  formData.append('description', description);

  images.forEach((image, index) => {
    formData.append(`images[${index}]`, image);
  });


  // Make the API call to add the product
  const response = await addProduct(formData);

  // Handle the response as needed
  console.log(response.data);

  // Optionally, you can perform additional actions after adding the product

  // Close the modal
  onClose();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error.message);
}
};

if (!isOpen) return null;

 return ( 
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data"> 
<div className="modalOverlay"> <div className="modalContent"> <div className="modalHeader"> <span className="modalTitle">{title}</span> <button className="closeButton" onClick={onClose}> X </button> </div> <div className="modalBody"> <div> <label>Title:</label> <input type="text" name="titles" value={titles} onChange={(event) => setTitle(event.target.value)} /> </div>

 {/* RAM Input */}
      <div>
        <label htmlFor='ram'>RAM:</label>
        <input type="text" name="ram"  value={ram} onChange={(event) => setRam(event.target.value)}/>
      </div>

      {/* Price Input */}
      <div>
        <label>Price:</label>
        <input type="text" name="price" value={price} onChange={(event) => setPrice(event.target.value)} />
      </div>

      {/* Total Products Input */}
      <div>
        <label>Total Products:</label>
        <input type="number" name="totalProducts" value={totalProducts} onChange={(event) => setTotalProducts(event.target.value)} />
      </div>

      {/* Description Input */}
      <div>
        <label>Description:</label>
        <textarea type='text' name="description" value={description} onChange={(event) => setDescription(event.target.value)}/>
      </div>
      {/* Multiple Image Upload Input */}
      <div className="imageUploadContainer">
        <label className="uploadLabel">Upload Images:</label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple onChange={handleImageChange} />
      </div>

      {/* Image Previews */}
      <div className="imagePreviewContainer">
        {previewImages.map((preview, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="imagePreviewItem">
            <img src={preview} alt={`Preview ${index}`} className="imagePreview" />
            <button onClick={() => removeImage(index)} className="removeButton">
              Remove
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      {/* Submit Button */}
      <button className="submitProButton" type='submit'>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
);};

export default Modal;
```

this is the controller function

```
const addProduct = async (req, res) => { 
try {const images = req.files && req.files.length > 0 ? req.files.map(file => file.path) : [];

  const {
    title,
    ram,
    price,
    totalProducts,
    description,
  } = req.body;

  // Note: image is not directly accessible from req.body when using FormData
  


  const newProduct = new productModel({
    title:title,
    ram:ram,
    price:price,
    totalProducts:totalProducts,
    description:description,
    image: images ? images.path : '', // Assuming you save the image path in your model
  });

  await newProduct.save();

  res.status(201).json({ message: 'Product added successfully', product: newProduct });
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error.message);
  res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server Error' });
}};``
```

I'm trying to build an e-commerce application using React and Node.js. The problem I encountered is that when I try to add a new product, the details are not reaching the backend. I used FormData to append all the details, including images, to send to the backend. It correctly gives every value from the frontend, but when it reaches the backend controller, it's empty. I logged it using console.log(req.body), and it shows an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use ExpressJS ?

If so, by default, an Express server is not able to handle *'multipart/form-data'* requests.

You need a middleware called Multer in order to be able to handle such requests.

I believe that by default you can `console.log(req.body)` and you should see something, but `console.log(req.files)` won't work without a middleware like Multer.

Example:

```
//This would go in your app.js or server.js file.
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post('/upload', upload.array('images'), (req, res) => {...}
```

From here:

- Uploaded files are available in req.files array
- Other form fields are available in req.body

Note that the above 'images' should always match the name attribute in the form field. In this example, the HTML would have `<input type="file" name="images" />` somewhere in the DOM.

Good luck!

Edit: I just noticed that in the code you provided, you never initialized your FormData. Before appending elements to a FormData you must initialize it first:

```
let formData = new FormData() //This is the line that your code is missing
formData.append('name', 'Mathurin')
formData.append('lastname', 'Farms')
```

Comment: actually i used multer to handle files

router.post('/addProduct', upload.array('image',3),addProduct)

still the problem not solved... everything appended on formData when i logged using (formData.get(''))... but when its reach backend its an empty object